# Microsoft.Office.Core is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly office, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: office-interop, excel-interop, .net-6.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I have created a .net 6 project.
I added the COM references: **Microsoft Excel 16 Object Library** (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) and **Microsoft Office 16 Object Library** (Microsoft.Office.Core).

The following lines of Excel interop code threw an error `at SetElement()`, could not build:

```
Chart c = (Chart)wbSheets.Application.Workbooks[1].Charts.Add();
chart.SetElement(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType.msoElementChartTitleAboveChart);
```

> Microsoft.Office.Core... is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly office, Version=15.0.0.0, ..., PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c

A very strange error, that an Office 16 (Office 2016) libary needs references to Office 15 (Office 2013).

The exact same steps for COM referencing and c# code works perfectly in .NET 4.8 Framework. So the problem is specific to .NET 6 (possibly .NET 5 and all previous .NET Core versions).

Using a nuget command `Install-Package MicrosoftOfficeCore -Version 15.0.0` to install the reference and manually removing the previous v16 reference, did resolve the code building error. But now the dependency had a yellow triangle warning, that the dependency is for .NET 4.6-4.8 Framework and might be incompatible with .NET 6.

Despite this, the code seemed to work and the Excel file was generated.

But I'll post a better fix in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better fix is to go to:

```
Solution Explorer > project > Dependencies > COM > select Microsoft.Office.Core > properties pane.
```

The last property is Wrapper Tool, with a default value of `tlbimp`

Type in `primary` for the value, click somewhere else to update the field and the problem is solved. No nuget package required.

Found this obscure solution from here (bottom most post):
https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5735